# Foreach works with template but breaks without template

Tags: javascript, templates, knockout.js, foreach

I have the following code that loads data for the view model via AJAX and displays it:

```html
<tbody id="filtered-table" data-bind="template: {name:'asset', foreach:assets}">

</tbody>
```

And the template looks like this:

```html
<script type="text/html" id="asset">
<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle" data-bind="text: id">&nbsp;</td>

    <td><img data-bind="attr:{ src: '/manager/files/' + poster }" height="100px" /></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle"><span dir="auto" data-bind="text: name"></span></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle" data-bind="text: category"></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle" data-bind="text: type"></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle" data-bind="text: popup"></td>

</tr>
</script>
```

And everything works fine.

The problem is that I do not want to use the template, instead I want to change a `foreach` bound element looking like this:

```html
<tbody id="filtered-table" data-bind="foreach: assets, visible: assets().length > 0">
    <tr >
        <td style="vertical-align: middle" data-bind="text: id">&nbsp;</td>
        <td><img data-bind="attr:{ src: '/manager/files/' + poster }" height="100px" /></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle"><span dir="auto" data-bind="text: name"></span></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle" data-bind="text: category"></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle" data-bind="text: type"></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle" data-bind="text: popup"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Even though I didn't change anything in the view model (I just took the html elements out of the template and put them into the foreach binded element) I get the following error:

> `Uncaught Error: Unable to parse binding attribute.`
>   `Message: ReferenceError: id is not defined;`
>   `Attribute value: text: id`

I would very much appreciate it if someone could explain what I am doing wrong. TIA!

Here is the viewModel and Ajax code part:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
        url: '/Assets/getJson/',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var viewModel = new ViewModel(data);

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        }
    });
});

function ViewModel(assets) {
  var self = this;

  self.assets = ko.observableArray(assets);
  self.allAssets = assets;
  self.query = ko.observable('');

  self.search = function(value) {
      self.assets.removeAll();
      for(var x in self.allAssets) {
        if(self.allAssets[x].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
          self.assets.push(self.allAssets[x]);
        }
      }
  };

  self.query.subscribe(self.search);
}
```

Here is a snippet of the response data (1st result):

```
{"id":"2","name":"\u05d9\u05e0\u05d8\u05dc","poster":"Pic011.jpg","category":null,"type":"Movie","popup":null}
```

Comment: Can you post your viewmodel code or your retrieved data from AJAX look like ? i see there on your template code there not have `id` attribute binding but on your foreach element has id attribute, might be you missing your id element in your retrieved data ?

Comment: I have check and I defiantly have the ID element in my retireved data

Comment: The code you posted [seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/m4xYv/). Please include the code in a way it's a [minimal repro](http://sscce.org), possibly even *backed* by a fiddle.

Comment: Yes, when the data is not loaded by ajax everything seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/eCLQK/  I do not know how to do ajax requests in jsFiddle, but in my code I tried it with static array and ajax, the static array worked, when loaded data via AJAX it didnt work. The problem seems to be that the observable array is populated after the ajax request completes.

Answer (score 0):

Your template includes this line:

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle" data-bind="text: type">&nbsp;</td>
```

The equivalent line in the non-template code:

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle" data-bind="text: id">&nbsp;</td>
```

In copying it, you appeared to have changed `type` to `id`. Try changing it back to `type` and see if that works.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but by accident I left the type in the template while I was trying to debug the problem. I have updated my question